# Finding hashtable collisions and printing

Tags: java, hash, hashtable, collision-detection

I'm trying to find a way to search a (java) hashtable and print out elements that have the same value. For example, if I were to search a hashtable of Strings with int values that represent their ASCII values, I would need to print all instances of collisions in the table (such as words that contain the same letters, like "state" and "taste", they would share the same ASCII value and need to both be printed).
I attempted to use the containsValue() function to add the results to a String array but it wont capture the first instance of collision (because it wasn't a match when I checked the value the first time.) 
 How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Start by building a Map<Integer, List<String>>

Comment: @cppbeginner Okay that makes sense, thank you. Now how can I go about adding to the list when I input values? e.g. how can I add values from the command line (strings) into the list at the given value? Does the created list have a name?

Comment: Are you going to use your own hashcode or the system default?